# I need to pass id from selected value in react to another table in Postgresql(using sqlAlchemy)

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have problems with frontend(react), i don't know how to pass id of selected option to backend(to another table ForeignKey Group_id). I'm using sqlAlcehmy

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';


const DropGroups = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [group, setGroup] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/api/getGroups')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setGroup(data))
    }, [id])

    return (
        <select>
            { group.map(data => <option key = { data.id } value={ data.id } name="Group_id">{ data.GroupName }</option>) }
        </select>
    )
}

export default DropGroups;
```

This is my MAIN component

```
  handleUploadImage(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.uploadInput.files[0]);
    data.append('filename', this.fileName.value);
    data.append('group_id', this.Group_id.value);

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/upload', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      filename: this.fileName,
      group_id: this.Group_id
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleUploadImage}>
        <div>
          <input ref={(ref) => { this.uploadInput = ref; }} type="file" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input ref={(ref) => { this.fileName = ref; }} type="text" placeholder="Enter the desired name of file" name="filename"/>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <DropGroups />
        <br />
          <button>Upload</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

These are my models and routes.

```
class Groups(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    GroupName = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, GroupName):
        self.GroupName = GroupName


class Files(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    FileName = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)
    Group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('groups.id'))

    def __init__(self, FileName):
        self.FileName = FileName

@app.route('/api/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def fileUpload():
    target = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, 'test_docs')

    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    new_fileName = request.form.get('filename')

    logger.info("welcome to upload`")
    file = request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    destination = "/".join([target, new_fileName])
    file.save(destination)
    session['uploadFilePath'] = destination

    uploadToDb = Files(
        FileName=request.form.get('filename'),
        Group_id=request.form.get('Group_id')
    )
    db.session.add(uploadToDb)
    db.session.commit()

    return 'Saved file infos'
```

**I get an error that says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined. only for group_id**